# Can we run two Lan cards simultaneously?

Tags: lan

am using windows 7 . am having two lan cards one is a built in onboard card and the other is seperate one. can i use two lan cards simultaneously for accessing the two different internet connections??

Comment: I would advice you to test out pfsense2.0. Using that you can load balance your network connections. You would need another computer to work as a router tough!

Answer (score 5):

> So you have two independent legal
>   Broadband accounts (can be two DSL two
>   Cable or one of each.)
>
> There are two terms that might be
>   associated with using two independent
>   Internet connections.
>
> 1. Combining Bandwidth.
> 2. Load Balancing two connections.
>
> Let assume that you have two 3Mb/sec.
>   connections each capable to download
>   at 300KB/sec.
>
> With Combined Bandwidth you should be
>   able to download one file at
>   600KB/sec.
>
> With Load Balancing one single file
>   will not exceed download speed of
>   300KB/sec.  However you can download 2
>   files at 300KB/sec. or 4 files at
>   150KB/sec. etc.
>
> Unfortunately Combining Bandwidth can
>   not be done without the ISP providing
>   such a specific service.
>
> Computers are Not mind readers. If the
>   two connections are not synchronized
>   at the source your computer would know
>   how to combine it to a coherent page.
>
> Any if and but about it is just
>   Wishful thinking.
>
> The price of such a service (if
>   available) is usually much more
>   expensive than upgrading your
>   connection from the basic service to a
>   faster business or corporate service.
>
> If you do have two independent
>   services you can achieve Load
>   Balancing by using a Dual WAN Router.
>
> This type of Cable/DSL Routers have
>   two WAN connections for two Broadband
>   Modems and they would mange the
>   Internet traffic to the LAN to be used
>   in the most efficient way.

*[Source](http://www.ezlan.net/loadbalance.html)*

Comment: +1 Excellent. Will refer to this answer to lots more folks when they keep asking why isn't it possible.

Comment: well, it's NOT impossible, but certainly not as easy as using 2 NICs on 2 independent internet connection. if you have an older spare box, you can run Vyatta on it, which features Load Balancing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

But the benefits of doing so are not as simple. The two connections will not automatically make your access speed faster, you cannot simply assume the two connections will mix together.

Also, it might not make your connection more reliable, if one network malfunctions, it does not mean that your system will automatically use the other connection correctly in all cases.